# How to access many to many object in .NET MVC via Razor

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Using EF 7 I have an object that references a many to many table, using code first method.

```
public class EventUser
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I can pull a list of these when knowing EventId and display them in Razor.  I want to link to each one of these objects back to the controller so a user could edit the AdditionalInfo field.  Since the object doesn't have just one Id field, how can I send the appropriate data to the controller to access this object, since just using one Id will not be enough.

At this point, I can achieve this using:

```
<a asp-action="EditEventUser" asp-route-EventId="EventUser.EventId" asp-route-UserId="EventUser.UserId">Edit Event User</a>
```

But, I would like to know if I am ignorant about some other way this can be achieved in a cleaner way (if there is such a way).

Comment: Why not just use EventId like you did to pull the original data?

Comment: I will have multiple EventUser table rows that will have the same EventId.  The combination of UserId and EventId is what will make them unique.  Many to many table.